# Django model how to add filter condition of through model field

Tags: python, django

I've two model class and a Through class as:

```
class Terms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField("Post", through="TermRelation")

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Categories and Tags
    terms = models.ManyToManyField("Term", through="TermRelation")

class TermRelation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_term_relation"
        unique_together = (
            ("term", "term_type", "post"),
        )

    CITES = (
        ('CAT', 'Category'),
        ('TAG', 'Tag'),
    )

    term = models.ForeignKey(Term, db_column="id_term")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, db_column="id_post")
    term_type = models.CharField('Term Type', max_length=3,
                                 default=CITES[0][0], choices=CITES)
```

Here I want to select only those type of Posts that is in Category `Java`.

**So, I'm doing in this way, but this is throwing exception:**

```
Post.objects.filter(terms__name='Java', termrelation_set__term_type='CAT')
```

**As SQL Expect:**

```
SELECT ... FROM Post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN TermRelation r ON p.id = r.id_post
LEFT OUTER JOIN Term t ON t.id = r.id_term
WHERE r.term_type = 'CAT'
      AND t.name = 'Java';
```

Please help me, what should I do?

Comment: Instead of `termrelation_set__term_type`, try `termrelation__term_type`

Comment: @Bibhas thanks, `termrelation__term_type` works. Many many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `termrelation_set__term_type`, try `termrelation__term_type`. Taking the hint from [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) -

```
As you are using an intermediate model, you can also query on its attributes:

# Find all the members of the Beatles that joined after 1 Jan 1961
>>> Person.objects.filter(
...     group__name='The Beatles',
...     membership__date_joined__gt=date(1961,1,1))
[<Person: Ringo Starr]
```